# Trying to get a user's userID post authentication in MVC3 using ASP.NET memberships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

We need to process something specific when the user logs into our MVC3 web app, so it's  wired inside global.asax.cs as follows:

```
    public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity != null)
        {
            MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser();
            // blah blah ... kick off something special
            // for logged in users here
        }
    }
```

Right now I'm getting the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This method can only be called after the authentication event.
```

at the line `args.Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity != null` which is in there to avoid tripping over `Membership.GetUser();` I suspect the choice of using `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` is not an appropriate choice and I'm hunting for the appropriate event and function ([lifetime and events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) without a clear answer in sight.

Am I really off in the wrong direction on this one? What is the best event/function to hook into to process this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hm... LogonUserIdentity a WindowsIdentity object for the current Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) authentication settings. You are trying to access this property from `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate`. Looks weird.

Comment: Anyway try `Application_AcquireRequestState`

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. Using the global.asax event Application_AuthorizeRequest instead of FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate worked for me.